# Magento frustrating memory limit

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.5

I am working with Magento for quite some time, but recently i am getting frustrated as I am getting an "Allowed memory size" error. This is usually fixed (from my understanding) by increasing the "php_value memory_limit" in the related .htaccess file which I have set to a high value since the day I launched my store.

In any case though I am recently getting the following errors in my error_log:

```
    PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 52428800 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 10282 bytes) in /home/store/public_html/includes/src/__default.php on line 2976
    PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 52428800 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /home/store/public_html/includes/src/__default.php on line 56485
    PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 52428800 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 77 bytes) in /home/store/public_html/includes/src/__default.php on line 56485
```

If it helps I will point out the related lines as follow. (the lines in questions are marked with ** **)

2976:

```
    try {
        $includeFilePath = realpath($this->_viewDir . DS . $fileName);
        if (strpos($includeFilePath, realpath($this->_viewDir)) === 0 || $this->_getAllowSymlinks()) {
            **include $includeFilePath;**
        } else {
            Mage::log('Not valid template file:'.$fileName, Zend_Log::CRIT, null, null, true);
        }
```

56485:

```
public function fetchAll($style = null, $col = null)
{
    if ($style === null) {
        $style = $this->_fetchMode;
    }
    try {
        if ($style == PDO::FETCH_COLUMN) {
            if ($col === null) {
                $col = 0;
            }
            return $this->_stmt->fetchAll($style, $col);
        } else {
            **return $this->_stmt->fetchAll($style);**
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        #require_once 'Zend/Db/Statement/Exception.php';
        throw new Zend_Db_Statement_Exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e);
    }
}
```

What seems strange to me here are the "52428800 bytes" which from my understanding translate to 50MB. Where could these 50MB be predefined? I clearly checked my php info and the value is nowhere to be seen, also the "php_value memory_limit" corresponds to what I have defined earlier and is nowhere close to 50MB.

My Magento setup:

- Magento 1.5.10
- Memcache enabled
- Compilation enabled

Hardware setup:

- VPS with 12GB RAM
- WHM / cPanel
- NginxCP

Current PHP configuration:

- Default PHP Version (.php files) 5
- PHP 5 Handler    dso
- PHP 4 Handler    none
- Apache suEXEC    on
- Apache Ruid2         on

I would be really thankful if someone someone is able to point me in the right direction on how to have this issues resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This can be set in

1. The `php.ini` file
2. Your Apache configuration (`.htaccess` or `http.conf`/it's includes)
3. At runtime with a call to `ini_set`

More likely though is your webhost has installed a third party PHP extension that limits memory, (such as [suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/).  I'd contact them first before spending to much time chasing at ghosts.

Comment: Thanks for the info Mr. Storm. As mentioned the .htaccess file already features a high value. I've quickly checked the PHP configuration editor in my VPS and the Core memory_limit is also set pretty high. (2048 MB). Any ideas? PS: I've added my current PHP configuration scope in the initial post

Comment: Try creating a quick file with a phpinfo(); call, it'll tell you what the memory limit is currently set to (and if suhosin is installed).  http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php

Comment: @nickyfsh Like Roscius says, run a phpinfo(); somewhere to get a snapshot of the current configuration.

Comment: Dear all, thank you very much. I've see to work with the outlined ini_set method for a couple of days but yet again I'm back at getting "Allowed memory size of 52428800 bytes exhausted" errors all over the place. I have a phpinfo script in place as mentioned in my initial post and the CORE memory_limit is definitely set high - I have the same number in my .htaccess. I can also say that the mentioned phpinfo shows that Suhosin is installed. Now what is puzzling to me is the "52428800 bytes " value which I don't know where to attribute. Could this be directly related to memcached? To Suhosin?

Comment: If it helps I've noticed that my current suhosin.memory_limit is set to 0